# How to list all users and the number of processes they have active

Tags: c, linux

I've got a task to write a program that lists all active users, and the ammount of processes they have active, when the program receives a SIGHUP signal, and exits, when it gets a SIGINT signal.

I've got this for listing users and process count

```
ps -u "$(echo $(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u))" o user= | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

And this is where i got with my program. I might be going about it the wrong way and could use a bit of help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sig_handler(int signo) {
  if (signo == SIGHUP){
    int pid = 0;
    if (pid = fork() != 0) {
      execl("/bin/ps", "ps", "-u", "\"$(echo $(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u))\"", "o", "user=", "|", "sort", "|",  "uniq", "-c", "|", "sort", "-rn", NULL);
    } else {
      printf("Signal received: SIGINT\nReported by: Parent process\n\n");
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  if (signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    printf("\nCan't catch SIGINT\n");

  while (1)
    sleep(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, I'm guessing you're supposed to use a lower-level approach, such as reading `proc` directly, instead of just `exec`-ing existing tools.

Comment: Interesting reading, examples and libraries here: http://procps.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Besides the precedence problem detailed in my answer, what's wrong with the code? What happens? What's supposed to happen? Please elaborate.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Running it i get error: user name does not exist, I'm guessing i can't use "$(echo $(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sort -u))" the way that i have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The line

```
if (pid = fork() != 0) {
```

does not do what you think it does!

In fact the compiler sees it as

```
if (pid = (fork() != 0)) {
```

This means, among other things, that you run the `execl` in the parent process, and not the child which is customary.

---

As for your problem, it's because you try to run shell-specific things (embedded commands, piping etc.) but you're not actually running a shell.

Either you have to `exec` a shell, or use the e.g. the `system` function.

Comment: I used the system function. Thanks for your input, it helped a lot.